# What QBFC API do I use for Vendor Credit?

Tags: c#, winforms, quickbooks, qbfc

For vendor invoices I'm using QBFC13lib.IBillAdd.

In testing...some of the data has negative amounts.
This would be a vendor credit. What is the interface for that?

I'm pretty much scratching my head looking at the Onscreen reference.
(using C#)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look in the QuickBooks OSR yet?

Perhaps at the option labeled `VendorCreditAdd`?

[image]

Comment: I completely missed it! It looks like its exactly like the BillAdd with the exception of the duedate.

Comment: Yep, they are extremely similar! Glad I could help!